# Press ENTER to exit program in Python not working

Tags: python, exit-code

Trying to get my code to exit on the press of the enter button and I'm running into a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`, but it's telling me that my error is on the line `simulations_num = int(simulations)`. Anybody have an idea?

```
simulations = input("How many times would you like to run the simulation? ")

# Invalid answer, system exit
if (not simulations) or int(simulations) <=0:    
   print("That is not a valid number of simulations.")
   print("Shutting down.")
   SystemExit

simulations_num = int(simulations)
#the rest of my code comes here
```

I've also attempted `if simulations == ''` to no avail.
I have noticed that if `simulations_num = int(simulations)` isn't involved, the code works fine, but that part of the code (or something similar) is necessary for the rest of the code

Comment: The `ValueError` is from trying to convert a letter/character to int.

Comment: `SystemExit` is an expression, not a call to an exit function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `raise SystemExit()`, or just use `sys.exit()` (which does the same thing).

Comment: I though the SystemExit was interchangeable with sys.exit() for some reason. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Mr.Oddicus It is, the important part is that you need to **raise** it, otherwise its just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

you need to raise an error, or at least use `sys.exit(0)`.
The working principle is this:

```
import sys
if not input(': ').lower() in ['yes','y','1']:
    sys.exit(0)
```

applied to your example would be this

```
simulations = input("How many times would you like to run the simulation? ")

import sys

# Invalid answer, system exit
if (not simulations) or int(simulations) <=0:    
   print("That is not a valid number of simulations.")
   print("Shutting down.")
   sys.exit(0)

simulations_num = int(simulations)
#the rest of my code comes here
```

`raise RuntimeError()` would also be good

Answer (score 0):

To address your code:

First of all, you need to add the "raise" keyword infront of SystemExit for it to work properly.
Second, to build a situation, in which you have to press Enter for the program to exit, you can use input().

Corrected Version:

```
simulations = input("How many times would you like to run the simulation? ")

# Invalid answer, system exit
if (not simulations) or int(simulations) <= 0:
    print("That is not a valid number of simulations.")
    print("Shutting down.")
    input("Press Enter to exit...")
    raise SystemExit("Exiting... Reason: invalid input!")

simulations_num = int(simulations)
# the rest of my code comes here
```